# JSF - passing parameter to @PostConstruct method

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, ejb

I've got a little problem with passing a parameter to @PostConstruct method of my @ManagedBean. I already know it can't be done just like that, but I also don't know how it can be done.

Let's start with some code:

```
    <h:form>
                <h:dataTable value="#{accountsList.accountsList}" var="konto">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">#{messages.id}</f:facet>
                        #{konto.id}
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">#{messages.login}</f:facet>
                        <h:commandLink value="#{konto.login}" action="#{profileViewer.showProfile()}" />
                    </h:column>
                    .........
                </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

The xhtml above is used to display accounts list.

Take a look at the commandLink. I would like to pass it's value (user's login) as a parameter to the action method which is a PostConstruct method of ProfileViewer bean.

Here's the ProfileViewer bean code:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ProfileViewer {

@EJB
private MokEndpointLocal mokEndpoint;

private Konta konto;

private String login;

@PostConstruct
public String showProfile(){
    konto = mokEndpoint.getAccountByLogin(login);
    return "profile";
}

public Konta getKonto() {
    return konto;
}

public void setKonto(Konta konto) {
    this.konto = konto;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public ProfileViewer() {
}
}
```

How can I do this? Please help me! I would appreciate an answer with an easy and good solution and some code.

Ok, I'll say it this way:
I've got a JSF page displaying list of accounts. I want each account name (login) to be a link to profile info (which is other jsf page displaying info about selected account)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to attain here? Please remove unnecessary variables so that the question is clearer.

Comment: Go through this link, http://balusc.blogspot.in/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html. It gives a clear idea about communications in JSF-2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never try to play with view parameters in `@PostConstruct` method. That's being called just after constructor and JSF doesn't have established values on it. Appart from that, you should remove `@PostConstruct` annotation from the action method and after that you can pass the user login value in multiple ways from a `h:commandLink`:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/

- **#{profileViewer.showProfile(login)}**
- **f:param name="user" value="login"**
- **f:atribute name="user" value="login"**
- **f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{profileViewer.showProfile}" value="login"**

Be careful if declaring `#{profileViewer.showProfile(login)}`, some servers can have problems with that:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-pass-parameters-in-method-expression-jsf-2-0/